# Hide entries from shorttoc but not from toc

Tags: shorttoc

I am a new user of TeXworks. I would like to hide some lines from my Summary (for which I use the `\shorttoc` command) but to keep them in the Table of Contents at the end of my document.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{shorttoc}

\begin{document}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}
I would like to thank...

\newpage{}
\shorttoc{Summary}{1}

\section*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
Here I write the abstract

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
Here I write the introduction

\section{Part1}
Here I write my part 1
\section{Part2}
Here I write my part 2

\section*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Conclusion}
Here I write my conclusion

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
\bibitem{key-1}\noun{Author 1}, ``Book name'', Editor, 1998.
\end{thebibliography}

\tableofcontents
```

I want `\shorttoc` to show the names of the sections only from the introduction to the conclusion (so I would like to hide the Acknowledgements, Abstract and Bibliography from the `\shorttoc`) but to keep all the names in the long TOC.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `shorttoc` you can only decide the level of depth of your additional ToC.

I think it's better to use `titletoc`, in your case.

In the MWE I've created a customized ToC named `myshort`.

*Edit:* If you put the `\section` to be listed in the short ToC within

```
\resumecontents[myshort]
...
\stopcontents[myshort]
```

you are free to choose which one goes into your short ToC.

For convenience, I've created a couple of macros.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{titletoc} 

\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}% Otherwise, the title is different from the ToC 

\newcommand{\secinstoc}[1]{% for convenience, I've created a macro for the section (not starred) to be added in the short ToC
\resumecontents[myshort]
\section{#1}
\stopcontents[myshort]
}
\newcommand{\secinstocs}[1]{% and the version with the starred \section*
\resumecontents[myshort]
\section*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1} 
\stopcontents[myshort]
}

\begin{document} 
\section*{Acknowledgements} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements} I would like to thank... 
\clearpage 

\startcontents[myshort] 
\stopcontents[myshort] 
\printcontents[myshort]{}{-1}{\section*{Summary}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary} 
\clearpage 

\section*{Abstract} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract} 
Here I write the abstract 
\secinstocs{Introduction} 
Here I write the introduction 
\subsection{This is not in my short ToC}
\secinstoc{Part1}
 Here I write my part 1 
\subsection{This is not in my short ToC}
\secinstoc{Part2} Here I write my part 2 
\subsection{This is not in my short ToC}
\subsection{This is not in my short ToC}
\secinstocs{Conclusion}
Here I write my conclusion 
\begin{thebibliography}{1} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography} 
\bibitem{key-1} Author 1 {``Book name''} Editor 1998.% I've not used \name because it gives an error 
\end{thebibliography} 
\clearpage 

\tableofcontents 
\end{document}
```

Page with the short ToC:

[image]

Page with the ToC:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it is nearly exactly what I wanted. Just to be what I really need, is it possible to combine this with shorttoc ? In my summary I would like to have only the sections (and introduction and conclusion) but not the subsections or under.

Comment: Thank you very much CarlLaTeX now it is exactly what I wanted !